# Can i use Float32 messages with the talker example in ROS2?

Tags: ros, ros2, talker, add-message-files

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of the normal `std_msgs::string`, i want to use `std_msgs::Float32` in the demo_nodes_cpp talker example.

is it possible to directly replace string with float32 as both belong to std_msgs or do i need to create a new custom message definition ?

I want to do something like this :

> ```
> class Talker : public rclcpp::Node
> ```

```
   {
   public:
   explicit Talker(const std::string & topic_name)
   : Node("talker")
   {
   msg_ = std::make_shared<std_msgs::msg::Float32>();

  // Create a function for when messages are to be sent.
  auto publish_message =
  [this]() -> void
  {
count_++;
if (count_ <= 50){
    msg_->data = 100;}

if (count_ > 50)
{
    msg_->data = 0;}
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Publishing: '%f'", msg_->data)

    // Put the message into a queue to be processed by the middleware.
    // This call is non-blocking.
    pub_->publish(msg_);
  };
```

Is this possible ?

This is the actual code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <string>


#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "rcutils/cmdline_parser.h"

#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/float32.hpp"

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

void print_usage()
{
  printf("Usage for talker app:\n");
  printf("talker [-t topic_name] [-h]\n");
  printf("options:\n");
  printf("-h : Print this help function.\n");
  printf("-t topic_name : Specify the topic on which to publish. Defaults to chatter.\n");
}

// Create a Talker class that subclasses the generic rclcpp::Node base class.
// The main function below will instantiate the class as a ROS node.
class Source : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  explicit Source(const std::string & topic_name)
  : Node("source")
  {
    heatflow_source = std::make_shared<std_msgs::msg::Float32>();

    // Create a function for when messages are to be sent.
    auto publish_message =
      [this]() -> void
      {
    count_++;
    if (count_ <= 50){
        heatflow_source->data = 100;}

    if (count_ > 50)
    {
        heatflow_source->data = 0.0;}
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Publishing: '%f'", heatflow_source->data)

        // Put the message into a queue to be processed by the middleware.
        // This call is non-blocking.
        pub_->publish(heatflow_source);
      };

    // Create a publisher with a custom Quality of Service profile.
    rmw_qos_profile_t custom_qos_profile = rmw_qos_profile_default;
    custom_qos_profile.depth = 7;
    pub_ = this->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::Float32>(topic_name, custom_qos_profile); //edited

    // Use a timer to schedule periodic message publishing.
    timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(1s, publish_message);
  }

private:
  size_t count_ = 1;
  std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::Float32> heatflow_source;
  rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::Float32>::SharedPtr pub_;
  rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  // Force flush of the stdout buffer.
  // This ensures a correct sync of all prints
  // even when executed simultaneously within the launch file.
  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, BUFSIZ);

  if (rcutils_cli_option_exist(argv, argv + argc, "-h")) {
    print_usage();
    return 0;
  }

  // Initialize any global resources needed by the middleware and the client library.
  // You must call this before using any other part of the ROS system.
  // This should be called once per process.
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

  // Parse the command line options.
  auto topic = std::string("heatflow_source");
  if (rcutils_cli_option_exist(argv, argv + argc, "-t")) {
    topic = std::string(rcutils_cli_get_option(argv, argv + argc, "-t"));
  }

  // Create a node.
  auto node = std::make_shared<Source>(topic);

  // spin will block until work comes in, execute work as it becomes available, and keep blocking.
  // It will only be interrupted by Ctrl-C.
  rclcpp::spin(node);

  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

I still get an error here :

error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__shared_ptrrclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::Float32_<std::allocator<void > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u>::__shared_ptr(std::remove_referencestd::__shared_ptr<rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void >, std::allocator >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u>&>::type)’
__shared_ptr(std::move(__r)).swap(*this);

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291427/can-i-use-float32-messages-with-the-talker-example-in-ros2-?/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-05-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-17**:
I'm going to say: yes.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-17**:
ok...it gives me this error in this case : `error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void> >::_data_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ and ‘int’) msg_->data = 0;}`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-17**:
I'm confused by the mention of `std_msgs::msg::String` in the error message. Did you update the type of the `msg_` member variable as well? You'll have to make sure to make these changes consistently, or things won't work.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-17**:
sorry ! yes now i did...with another error message `error: ‘Float32’ is not a member of ‘std_msgs::msg’ std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::Float32> msg_;` Do i need to declare some special header file ?

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2018-05-17**:
Each message generates its own set of headers. Replacing `#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"` by `#include "std_msgs/msg/float32.hpp"` should do the job

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-17**:
@marguedas: yes this would be an alternative but for this then i need to create another `msg` definition and build it to use `#include "std_msgs/msg/float32.hpp"` What i meant was since, float32 also belongs to the std_msgs class, shouldnt it be directly possible ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-17**:
No, you don't. `std_msgs` already contains a msg for `Float32`, so you can just reuse that.

> What i meant was since, float32 also belongs to the std_msgs class, shouldnt it be directly possible ?

yes, but you need to include the header. How else is the compiler going to know what you are using?

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2018-05-17**:\

> What i meant was since, float32 also belongs to the std_msgs class, shouldnt it be directly possible ?

Yes the `Float32` message class is already provided by the `std_msgs` package. So you can use it without creating a new msg definition. To use it you need to include `std_msgs/msg/float32.hpp`

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-17**:
Thank you all for your suggestions. Implemented the same but still a shared pointer error. Edited the question with the complete code. @marguedas @gvdhoorn

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-17**:
I found the mistake : while creating the publisher, i used String instead of Float32 and thus it showed an error that there was no matching function. Also edited in the question. Thanks for the support.

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2018-07-04**:
@aakash_sehgal: can you please summarize the solution and post it as an answer so that this question can be marked as solved? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, float32 messages could be used instead of string.

Just include the `std_msgs/msg/float32.hpp` and also keep in mind to update the type of the member variable `msg_`

---

Originally posted by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) with karma: 667 on 2018-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0